# Unable to export Jupyter notebook to Python Script in Azure ML Studio

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook

I am stuck on [step 5 in this Azure tutorial](https://microsoftlearning.github.io/mslearn-azure-ml/Instructions/08-Script-command-job.html):
[image]

Whenever I try to export to Python, I get a little message that says "Python export started, please wait..." that shows up for about 2 milliseconds, then disappears, with no popup or error message on my jupyter notebook. Has anyone else encountered this issue before? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the same using azure machine learning studio and when tried to export as **.py** python script file, got the same popup `Python export started.please wait...` and file is not exported.

[image]

You can use VS code to export it to `.py` file as fallback method.

- In Azure ML studio notebook, click *Edit in VS Code*.

[image]

- Once .ipynb file is opened in Visual Studio, open command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P). Type **Export to Python Script**.

[image]

- .py script file is opened in the new tab. Click File-> save and save the file in the same location with file name `train-classification-model.py`.
  [image]
- You can view the saved .py file in azure machine learning studio notebook file path also. Open the file in studio.

[image]

- Once the .py file is opened, you can follow the step:8 in that document ([mslearn-azure-ml (microsoftlearning.github.io)](https://microsoftlearning.github.io/mslearn-azure-ml/Instructions/08-Script-command-job.html)).

Comment: Glad the issue is not just on my end. Thank you and i will try the fallback method.

Comment: I have not had time to try it out personally on my end but I will give credit for the effort involved!